# Accessing and changing a jQuery plugin variable outside the plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've written a small jQuery plugin which looks for any changes to form inputs on the page, and alerts the user if they leave the page without saving.

The plugin looks like this:

```
(function ( $ ) {
    $.extend({
        unsaved: function() {
            var unsaved = false;

            $("form").find("input").on("change", function() {
                unsaved = true;
            });

            $("form").on("submit", function() {
                unsaved = false;
            });

            function unloadPage(){ 
                if (unsaved){
                    return "You have unsaved changes on this page. Do you want to leave this page and discard your changes or stay on this page?";
                }
            }
            window.onbeforeunload = unloadPage;
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

And I call it like this:

```
// Look out for unsaved data
$.unsaved();
```

However, I am now adding/removing some data using Ajax, and I would like to manually mark `unsaved` as true afterwards so that the user gets alerted if they try to leave the page without saving.

I guess what I'm looking to do is something like

```
// Call the plugin as normal
var unsaved = $.unsaved();

// Do some stuff with ajax here
// ...

// Manually mark the page as unsaved
unsaved.markAsUnsaved();
```

I have tried creating a `markAsUnsaved()` function within my plugin in all kinds of different ways, but cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

you must return your `markAsUnread` function:

```
(function ( $ ) {
     $.extend({
        unsaved: function() {
            var self = this;
            self.isUnsaved = false;

            $("form").find("input").on("change", function() {
                self.isUnsaved = true;
            });

            $("form").on("submit", function() {
                self.isUnsaved = false;
            });

            function unloadPage(){ 
                if (self.isUnsaved){
                    return "You have unsaved changes on this page. Do you want to leave this page and discard your changes or stay on this page?";
                }
            }
            window.onbeforeunload = unloadPage;
            return {
                markAsUnsaved: function() {
                    self.isUnsaved = true;
                };
            };
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

we use `self` as reference for `unsaved` plugin class, also rename `unsaved` boolean variable to different from plugin name. then plugin returns an object that contains markAsUnread function.